# attribute error: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-views

i am trying to make this request for a checkout id in a payment process and this is my code so far.
the code below works fine and i get a response from it, but as soon as I add some of the commented parts to the data dictionary it gives me an attribute error saying that int has no object get.

basically, i seem to only be able to add keys and string or number values to my data dict, but whenever i add a dict as a value it starts giving me the error.

i have no idea why this is happening, can anyone help? thanks in advance!

```
def request_checkout_id(request):

    user = request.user

    url = "https://xxxxxx"
    entity_id = 'xxxxx'
    auth_header = 'xxxxx'
    currency = 'USD'

    try:
        ref_code = request.session['ref_code']
        order = Order.objects.get(ref_code=ref_code)    
    except:
        ref_code = None
        return redirect(reverse('shop:cart'))

    amount = float(order.final_total)

    base_con_tarifa = order.cart.total
    valor_iva = order.cart.tax_total
    #total_con_iva = order.sub_total
    base_sin_tarifa = order.shipping_price
    custom_param = '0081004012'+ str(valor_iva).replace(".", "").zfill(12) + '052012' + str(base_sin_tarifa).replace(".", "").zfill(12) + '003007010391005100817913101053012' + str(base_con_tarifa).replace(".", "").zfill(12)
    print(custom_param)

    data = {}
    # cart = {}
    # items = []
    # i = 0
    # for item in order.cart.cartitem_set.all():
    #     items.append({})
    #     items[i]['name'] = item.product.name
    #     items[i]['description'] = item.product.description
    #     items[i]['price'] = item.product.price
    #     items[i]['quantity'] = str(item.quantity)
    #     i += 1
    # cart['items'] = items
    #customer = {}
    #customer['givenName'] = user.first_name
    #customer['surname'] = user.last_name
    # customer['merchantCustomerId'] = str(user.id)
    # #customer['phone'] = order.shipping_address.phone
    # customer['phone'] = '0987543493'
    # customer['identificationDocType'] = 'IDCARD'
    # customer['identificationDocId'] = '0926685432'
    #shipping = {}
    # shipping['street1'] = order.shipping_address.street_address
    # shipping['country'] = order.shipping_address.country
    #shipping['street1'] = 'aosidaoisd'
    #shipping['country'] = 'EC'
    #billing = {}
    # billing['street1'] = order.billing_address.street_address
    # billing['country'] = order.billing_address.country
    #billing['street1'] = 'aosidaoisASd'
    #billing['country'] = 'EC'
    data['entityId'] = entity_id
    data['amount'] = amount
    data['currency'] = currency
    data['paymentType'] = 'DB'
    data['testMode'] = 'EXTERNAL'
    data['merchantTransactionId'] = 'as09aSAS097'
    #data['customer'] = customer
    #data['cart'] = cart
    #data['shipping'] = shipping
    #data['billing'] = billing
    print(data)

    try:
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPHandler)
        request_id = urllib.request.Request(url, data=urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8'))
        request_id.add_header('Authorization', auth_header)
        request_id.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
        response = opener.open(request_id)
        parsed_response = json.loads(response.read())
        checkout_id = parsed_response['id']
        print(checkout_id)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print(e.code)
        return e.code

    if checkout_id:
        payment = Pago()
        payment.order = order
        payment.ref_code = order.ref_code
        payment.user = request.user
        payment.checkout_id = checkout_id
        payment.save()
        return redirect(reverse('shop:checkout'))
    #else:
    #raise some error or alert
```

this is my error traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /shop/checkout/request_checkout_id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roberto\radlab\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Roberto\radlab\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Roberto\radlab\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
[31/Aug/2020 17:21:59] "GET /shop/checkout/request_checkout_id HTTP/1.1" 500 64423
```

Comment: add your complete error traceback

Comment: i edited the post so you can see the error traceback @ArakkalAbu

Comment: you are returning `return e.code` at some point from the view. I think that causes the error. You have to return a ***HTTP Response*** from a Django view.

Comment: the code as posted works, its only when i start adding the commented parameters that throws the exception. it only returns e.code if there is an exception before it gets to that. how would i implement the httpresponse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it. I was just passing the data in the wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone reading this in the future, a simpler instance on where this error happens, and my solution.

```
# Python program for reading from file 

counts = dict() *# line that fixed it for me*

fname = input("Enter file name: ")

with open(fname) as fh:
    myfile = fh.read()
    words = list(myfile.split())

    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1

print('counts', counts)
```

As it turns out, if you don't define the counts as a `dict()` type it will throw the same **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'** error.
I am very new to Python so if this solution is too basic, its intent is towards someone who is also learning.

Answer (score 0):

As is pointed out in the comments, the problem is you're returning the status code as an `int` (`HTTPError.code`) in the `HTTPError` case, and Django needs it to be an `HTTPResponse`.

The simplest way to handle this would be to replace this logic:

```
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
    return e.code
```

with this:

```
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
    return HttpResponse(status=e.code)
```

Depending on your application, you may need more in your HTTPResponse, though. You can read more in the Django documentation for [returning errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/#returning-errors). There are also subclasses of `HTTPResponse` for specific status codes, so if you know that the error code is 500, you could return `HttpResponseServerError`.